# Фле(э)шбэк - какой вариант "частотнее" и "из серии «помните ли вы?» - поднимать "Помните"?

Tags: орфография, прописная-строчная

> У многих зрителей при взгляде на ведущую канала ТВЦ Ингу Ильм
>   возникает ощущение приятного **флэшбэка**. «Ещё не хватало, чтобы
>   интервью получилось из серии **«помните ли вы?»**, — брюзгливо
>   опасалась Алёна Полунина, собираясь на встречу с выросшей Машей
>   Старцевой из отличного детского фильма «Приключения Петрова и
>   Васечкина».

Два ***э*** в слове мне глаз режет...

Comment: Мне всё слово глаз режет. Таковы правила формальной  транскрипции - чтобы при "обратной её" **э** перешло в **а**, а не в **e**. Но похоже, всё-таки локализовать стали как и _флешку_ (первое - е, так в википедиях).

Comment: Спасибо. Приходи рассказывать про серию - ответом, плиз.

Comment: В принципе, можно написать и "флашбак", и это соответствует одному из принципов транскрипции, но, к сожалению, это не прижилось у нас в России. Хотя встречается иногда: *сандвич, Сандвичевы острова, Максвелл, сканер, скан.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Из словаря:

**1) флеш-.**.. – первая часть сложных слов, пишется через дефис

**2) флешбэк**, -а (кинематографический прием),   (англ. flash — вспышка, озарение; back — назад), — назад), **обратный кадр** — в искусстве — художественный приём, временное прекращение повествования сюжетной линии с целью демонстрации зрителю событий прошлого.

Таким образом, флешбек — **это как бы  "вспышка памяти".**

В заимствованных словах после Л обычно пишется Е, например: **сленг** [лэ],  м. [англ. slang]. Написание ***флеш*** также уже **закрепилось в языке** и отмечено в словарях, хотя форма *флэш* еще встречается в текстах.

Информация из Интернета (почему слова ***флешка*** и ***вспышка*** имеют общее происхождение

Флеш-память была открыта Фудзи Масуока (Fujio Masuoka), когда он работал в Toshiba в 1984. Имя «флеш» было придумано также в Toshiba коллегой Фудзи, Шойи Ариизуми (Shoji Ariizumi), потому что процесс стирания содержимого памяти ему напомнил фотовспышку (англ. flash).

**flash — вспышка, in a flash**  —  в мгновение ока, в один миг, в одно мгновение, в одночасье, в один момент.

2) **«Ещё не хватало, чтобы интервью получилось из серии  «помните ли вы?»**

Вроде бы всё нормально. Здесь серия — тип, жанр. Интервью **(какое?)** из серии «помните ли вы (этих героев)?», я так понимаю это определение. Приложение заключено в кавычки,  строчная буква — всё на месте. Это же не название реальной передачи, а только обозначение  жанра.

**СЕРИЯ**, -и; ж. [от лат. series - ряд] 1. Ряд однородных предметов (единого назначения, тематики, жанра и т.п.). С. рассказов для детей. С. карандашных рисунков.

Comment: Жасминчик! А вторая часть вопроса - про "из серии"?

Answer (score 1):

[Вопрос № 212389](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=212389)
Как правильно писать – "флешбек", "флэшбэк", "флэшбек" или как-то еще и какое точное определение этого слова?
Ответ справочной службы русского языка
Правильно: *флешбэк*.

> брюзгливо опасалась

Плохо сочетается, звучит странно. Не лучше ли сказать *брюзгливо выражала свои опасения* или просто *брюзжала*?

Comment: Так (правя "как у больших") мы автора убьём.